# How to set a predefined height or width for "grid-stack-item" with acceptWidgets

Tags: javascript, gridstack

I'm using gridstack with acceptWidgets to drag-and-drop widgets from a left side panel to the main panel, kind of similar to http://gridstackjs.com/demo/two.html

In my case, I want to set height, width and other [item attributes](https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/tree/develop/doc#item-attributes) to my "grid-stack-item". However, setting up those attributes won't affect when the item is dropped in the gridstack.

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/trevisan/wt7bg6s1/8/

Note that the "Drag me" element has data-gs-width="6" which I expected to make it stretch as my gridstack has 6 columns.

```
<div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-width="6">
  <div class="grid-stack-item-content">Drag me</div>
</div>
```

I have tried to call [makeWidget](https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/tree/develop/doc#makewidgetel) method but then I end up having two widgets on my gridstack.

Does anyone have an idea how to figure that out?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `Drag me` element is not in `gridstack` even it has class name "grid-stack-item",

`#grid` element and `#grid2` element has initialized by `gridstack` but `sidebar` element(`Drag me` element)  didn't:

```
        $('#grid1').gridstack(options);
        $('#grid2').gridstack(_.defaults({
            float: true
        }, options));
```

So the `data-gs-width` attribute means nothing to `Drag me` element.